# Add picture in Exam class

Tags: graphics, exam

I am writing assignment using `exam` class. I am having difficulty in adding pictures. Could anyone help me with it, please? The following is my work. As a test, I attach the following picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english, 11pt, hidelinks]{exam}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.5}

\printanswers
\unframedsolutions
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question

some text

\begin{parts}

\part Plot some graph

\begin{solution}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[sclae=0.8]{test}
\end{figure}

\end{solution}

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd start by replacing `sclae=0.8` with `scale=0.8`.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want it in a `figure` environment.

Comment: If I understand your setup, you do not want the graphs to "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word). Thus, don't use the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` wrappers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you need (or want) the graphs to "float about" -- in the LaTeX sense of word -- don't encase the `\includegraphics` directive in a `figure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english, 11pt, hidelinks]{exam}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.5}

\printanswers
\unframedsolutions
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{hyperref} % good idea to load this package last

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
   \question
   Some text
   \begin{parts}
      \part Plot a graph
      \begin{solution}

         %\begin{figure}[h] %Don't enclose graph in a "figure" env.
         \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{test}
         %\end{figure}
      \end{solution}
   \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But why did I have the problem in the first place, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan - You haven't been very specific so far as to the nature of the problem and/or error message you've been encountering. I can only assume that the error is related to LaTeX complaining that the float was encountered while "not in outer par mode". If this guess is correct, it means that LaTeX was trying to invoke its float-placement algorithms but couldn't do so because the `figure` environment occurs inside a `solutions` environment, which does not co-exist peacefully with LaTeX floats .

Comment: Is there anyway to have floating work in `figure` environment, please?

Comment: @LaTeXfan - Are you willing to switch document classes?